# SYNTAX ERROR , t_variable

Tags: php, syntax-error

I am trying to upload directly an image from a distant server to fb servers but there is an error syntax error in line 7 tell me what wrong with it

```
<?php
require_once("facebook.php");
$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$config[‘secret’] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$config[‘fileUpload’] = true/ optional
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$attachment = array('message' => 'Want an Amazing Cover for your profile then checkout the link below. ',
'name' =>'xxxxx',
'caption' => "xxxxxxx",
'link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx/',
'description' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', //blah blah
'picture' => 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/under-construction-fb-cover1.jpg'.$Picturetoupload,
'method'=>'stream.publish',
'actions' => array(array('name' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/axxxxxx/')));
$uid=$fbme['id'];  // id of the user 
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/feed/','post',$attachment);
?>
```

Comment: Please put the code in a code block and format so that it's readable.

Comment: Fun fact: if you get a t_variable error, don't ask why on SO. It's always your fault.

Comment: semi colon is missed on line 6

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a semi-colon on line 6 and are using an improper comment and quotes.

```
$config[‘fileUpload’] = true/ optional
```

Should be:

```
$config['fileUpload'] = true; // optional;
```

Comment: it was just a mistake of not giving 4 spaces to <?php and i had put that on other lines .

Comment: @JayantTyagi: Please edit your question, so it's clear that this is not the cause of error. Also, you need to highlight which line line 6 is, we don't have your file. Also please look for the related questions you find here on SO.